# Programmatically call SendTo

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

How can I programmatically(.net) call a command on the Windows explorer SendTo context menu option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that sendto items are filesystem objects is a implementation detail, the menu is filled by the sendto shell extension and it could be extended to include other things in the next version of windows etc. In fact, treating the sendto folder as just a folder of shortcuts that you can execute with a single parameter has been problematic since Windows95 ([powertoys/shell toys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145688))

Some of the sendto items are not .lnk's but unique file extensions with a registered drop handler (.DeskLink, .OtherFolder, .MAPIMail etc)

The documented way to invoke a sendto item would be to use [IContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The un-managed way to do this would be to call SHBindToParent on the object you want to emulate the sendto action on (asking for IID_IShellFolder) Then call [IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and ask for IID_IContextMenu, you can then call [IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to fill in a HMENU, you would then have to find the sendto submenu (I'm thinking it will return sendto as its verb if you ask it with IContextMenu::GetCommandString) You can then enumerate the submenu with the winapi menu functions and/or IContextMenu::GetCommandString to find the item you want to invoke, then call [IContextMenu::InvokeCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Should have kept the question open for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Sendto is simply a folder on the filesystem, so calling a command there is just running a file... for me it's located at:

C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo

Comment: 'so calling a command there is just running a file....' can you please elaborate. I just figured that you can get to the folder via the specialfolders...

Comment: When you right click `somefile.txt` and "send it to" an app, I believe the app is simply lanuched with `somefile.txt` as a commandline argument. So you could do it yourself with, say, `Process.Start()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx

Comment: This is not correct, if the (file) extension has a registered DropHandler, it will be called, if not then yes, it is pretty much like a Process.Start() call