# PowerShell: invoke Shell SendTo

Tags: powershell

Right-clicking on a file, you can `Send to...` → `Desktop` etc.

All these options are defined in the folder `shell:sendto`.

Is there any way I can invoke any of these options using PowerShell?

(The only information I can find right now is [Programmatically call SendTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586880/programmatically-call-sendto)).

[How to drop files onto .MAPIMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485978/how-to-drop-files-onto-mapimail)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have already solved the problem. But it aint a solution that I want to replicate for Thunderbird at home. I would rather have a solution that uses the contents of `shell:sendto` instead. My Outlook solution is in http://tahirhassan.blogspot.co.uk/2017/10/powershell-create-email-message-with.html